# New Pandas Groupby API Changes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, where rows have a Name, a Type, and an SLA column.  The SLA column is a numerical value: 1, 2 or 3.  The SLA column is specific to type, not name.

I have code that creates a new column, which groups by the name values, and enforces the same numerical value for all rows with the same name.  I.e. if all the SLA values for a given name are 2, then they all get 2.  If they are all 3, then they get 3.  Otherwise (if all values are 2 or more likely if there's a mix of values), they all get 2.

```
df['SLA_Norm'] = df.groupby('Name').apply(assignSLA)
```

With the function:

```
def assignSLA(df):
    a = pd.Series(df['SLA'], df.index)
    m = a.mean()
    if m == 1.0:
        n = [1]
        n = n*len(a)
        return pd.Series(n, df.index)
    elif m == 3.0:
        n = [3]
        n = n*len(a)
        return pd.Series(n, df.index)
    else:
        n = [2]
        n = n*len(a)
        return pd.Series(n, df.index)
```

After updating the pandas library, which recently updated the groupby api, this function breaks.  However, I can't figure out why.  Does anyone know why the new groupby functionality in pandas would break this function?

Thanks kindly.

EDIT:

So starting with df:

```
Name    Type    SLA
Foo     A       1       
Foo     B       2       
Foo     C       3       
Buzz    A       1       
Buzz    A       1       
Buzz    A       1       
Buzz    A       1       
Buzz    A       1       
Bar     C       3       
Bar     C       3       
Bar     C       3
```

I used to get, with pandas 13.0:

```
Name    Type    SLA     SLA_Norm
Foo     A       1       2
Foo     B       2       2
Foo     C       3       2
Buzz    A       1       1
Buzz    A       1       1
Buzz    A       1       1
Buzz    A       1       1
Buzz    A       1       1
Bar     C       3       3
Bar     C       3       3
Bar     C       3       3
```

Now I get, with pandas 14.0:

```
Name    Type    SLA     SLA_Norm
Foo     A       1       NaN
Foo     B       2       NaN
Foo     C       3       NaN
Buzz    A       1       NaN
Buzz    A       1       NaN
Buzz    A       1       NaN
Buzz    A       1       NaN
Buzz    A       1       NaN
Bar     C       3       NaN
Bar     C       3       NaN
Bar     C       3       NaN
```

Comment: you would have to post a complete starting frame, what version you were on, and what version you changed to. The API is backwards compat. So not sure what is 'breaking'

Comment: Will update question with all of that information.  Respectfully, this function ran successfully for several hundred days in a row, and then stopped functioning immediately upon updating pandas.

Comment: Edited the name to get rid of 'breaking' language, not trying to besmirch a library that makes my job possible..

Comment: It's also possible the change has nothing to do with groupby().  For example, might be something in pd.Series().

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to using pandas built in group by and then merge it with your original frame.  Try using this code...

```
means = df.groupby('Name')[['SLA']].mean()
df = pd.merge(df,means,left_on='Name',right_index=True,suffixes=("","_Norm"))
```

Edit

depending on what you want for your _Norm value you could also use `.apply(function)`

Comment: This is perfect.. without .astype(int) . Thanks.

Comment: I think the normal operation would be to do a `transform` on a groupby in order to return an object with it's indices aligned with the original df: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation